# 1950s sci-fi movie about a trip to Mars

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Ship from Earth crashes on Mars, and the crew asks the Martians (who just happen to look just like humans) for help repairing it. Martians agree, but plan to betray the humans and invade Earth.

Beautiful Daughter Of Martian Scientist falls in love with Earth captain and helps them to escape.  She returns to Earth with them.

The movie was made in the US, and I think I watched it on YouTube a few years ago.

Comment: Welcome to M&TV. Please add anything that can help identify this movie. Like when did you watch it or which country it belongs to or language of the movie or how characters looked like or any other plot details you remember. If you have added any of these details, very good. However, if you recall something, be it as the smallest detail, feel free to [edit](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/81641/edit) your question.

Comment: @AJ I added more, but the original question had as much as I could remember.

Answer (score 11):

It's the 1951 movie [Flight to Mars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043545/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

> The first expedition to Mars, led by physicist Dr. Lane (John Litel), includes Professor Jackson (Richard Gaines), engineer Jim Barker (Arthur Franz), and his assistant Carol Stadwick (Virginia Huston). Journalist Steve Abbott (Cameron Mitchell) is also aboard to cover the historic mission. A final interview with his crew mates before launch makes him realize that there are grave risks for them all.
>
> They lose contact with Earth when a meteor storm disables both their landing gear and radio. The crew is forced to decide whether to crash-land on Mars or turn back for Earth. Professor Jackson makes the case that the purpose of their expedition is to collect data, data which they can send back to Earth using self-propelled space cylinders equipped with homing devices. They decide to proceed with the mission, knowing they can never return.
>
> After they safely crash-land, the crew are met by five Martians at one of their above ground structures. Looking human and being able to communicate in English, their leader, Ikron (Morris Ankrum), the president of their planetary council, explains that they have been receiving Earth's broadcasts by which they learned our languages. Their own efforts, however, to transmit messages to Earth have only resulted in faint signals being transmitted.
>
> The Earth crew are brought by the Martians to a vast underground city, which is being sustained by life-support systems fueled by a mineral called Corium. There the crew meet Tillamar (Robert Barrat), a past president and now a trusted council advisor. Terris (Lucille Barkley), a young female Martian shows them to their room and serves the group automated meals. The expedition members are amazed at the high level of Martian technology around them and soon ask the council for help with repairing their spaceship.
>
> Discreetly, Ikron reveals that their Corium supply is nearly depleted. He recommends that the Earthmen's spaceship be reproduced, once repaired, creating a fleet that can evacuate the Martians to Earth. The council votes to adopt Ikron's plan, while also deciding to hold the Earthmen captive during the repair process. Alita (Marguerite Chapman), a leading Martian scientist, is placed in charge of the spaceship. Ikorn keeps himself informed of the progress by using Terris as a spy. Jim begins to suspect the Martians' motives and fakes an explosion aboard, slowing the ship's repairs. When Jim later announces their blast-off for Earth is set for the next day, he surprises everyone with the news that Tillamar and Alita will be joining them.Terris reports their suspicious behavior, leading to Alita and Tillimar being held, but Jim foils Ikron's plan to seize the repaired Earthship after freeing both. After a brief confrontation with Martian guards at the spaceship's gangway, the three make it aboard safely, and the expedition is able to safely blast-off for Earth.

Comment: Wow, that looks 50s-terrible! I love it!